# How to point an IFrame inside a div with css

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am trying to control the google recaptcha v2 used in mailpoet. I think I did it. But I guess if I change the default iframe it will cause problems..
I have the following

[image]

How to access iframe only of mailpoet_recaptcha with css?

.mailpoet_recaptcha>div>div>iframe{ } ?

Comment: luckily, we can't. And it's a good thing

Comment: You do have some level of control (mainly for grabbing info only, no editing) via javascript, but it's very limited.
As @MisterJojo mentioned, iframes are meant to be 1to1 interpretations of other sources, and editing them would defeat the whole purpose.

Comment: What else could someone do though if mailpoet on support forums says "we will not give you the option changing size of recaptcha"